# How to insert model from list into stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, list

My program is making a query from one database and I want that query to be added to a stored procedure in another database.
At first I was insert each parameter as a List, but I want to optimize the code and insert all parameters into one List.
I add all select options to list:

```
public void GetResult(SqlCommand command)
        {

            var list = new List<Models>;

            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var rows = new Models;
                    rows.Md1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["md1"]);
                    rows.Md2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["md2"]);

                    list.Add(rows);
                }

            using var InsertCommand = new OracleCommand();
            InsertCommand.CommandText = "PathToProcedure";

            var Param1 = new OracleParameter("param1", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirecion.Input);
            Param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            Param1.Value =
            Param2.Size = 


        }
```

Question: How to create a link to these rows to insert them in parameters?
Thanks in advance!

SP:

```
create or replace package body transfer_package is

procedure getdt(param1 in t_number,
                param2 in t_number)
        is
  begin
    if param1.count > 0 then
       for i in 1 .. param1.count loop
    insert into table
          (parameter1,
           parameter2)
        values
          (param1(i),
           param2(i));
      
        end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Could you show us your code of SP and your code look like incomplete?

Comment: @D-Shih SP was added in topic. Above in code, I simply connect the first database and "select" all records from it. There is nothing interesting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my question is a Linq library...

```
Param1.Value = list.Select(Models => Models.Md1).ToArray();
Param2.Size = list.Select(Models => Models.Md2).ToArray();
```

and so on